# Extending the API I created to return category names

Tags: api, rest-api, wp-api, plugin-json-api

I created [this api](https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ads) using a plugin called [WP REST API Controller.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-controller/) But it didn't return custom taxonomy categories

so I installed a plugin called [WP REST API – Pure Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-pure-taxonomies/), it's returning category parent, but I don't know what the parent name is, I don't even know if the parent is a category or a sub category

```
pure_taxonomies: {
ad_cat: [
{
term_id: 42,
name: "Nissan",
slug: "nissan",
term_group: 0,
term_taxonomy_id: 42,
taxonomy: "ad_cat",
description: "",
parent: 9,
count: 19,
filter: "raw",
term_type: "0",
term_font_icon: "0"
}
]
}
```

How to fix this? I am using a custom taxonomy with custom categories that are different than WordPress categories. The theme is [classipress](https://github.com/wp-premium/classipress). I don't think I can rely on plugins anymore, I think I have to do it manually, no plugin can help me with categories.

I want to return the name of the category, I want to know if it's a category or a sub category. I guess that parent is category, I wish there's a way to return its name though.

Comment: how do you register the taxonomy "ad_cat" ?

Comment: @mmm this plugin created them, i don't know how https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-pure-taxonomies/